# Using Integer[] vs. int[]

Tags: java, recursion, integer, boxing

I am trying to solve the following problem: "Write an algorithm to print all the ways of arranging eight queens on an 8x8 chess board so that none of them share the same row, column or diagonal (i.e. no two queens attack each other.)"

I am having trouble understanding why the author used Integer[] instead of the more common int[], for example in "Integer[] columns" and "ArrayList results" which are parameters to placeQueens.  My hypothesis is that this is due to generics in Java, but I'm not entirely sure.

Code snippet below. Link to complete code at bottom of page.

```
public static int GRID_SIZE = 8;

/* Check if (row1, column1) is a valid spot for a queen by checking if there
 * is a queen in the same column or diagonal. We don't need to check it for queens
 * in the same row because the calling placeQueen only attempts to place one queen at
 * a time. We know this row is empty. 
 */
public static boolean checkValid(Integer[] columns, int row1, int column1) {
    for (int row2 = 0; row2 < row1; row2++) {
        int column2 = columns[row2];
        /* Check if (row2, column2) invalidates (row1, column1) as a queen spot. */

        /* Check if rows have a queen in the same column */
        if (column1 == column2) { 
            return false;
        }

        /* Check diagonals: if the distance between the columns equals the distance
         * between the rows, then they're in the same diagonal.
         */
        int columnDistance = Math.abs(column2 - column1); 
        int rowDistance = row1 - row2; // row1 > row2, so no need to use absolute value
        if (columnDistance == rowDistance) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void placeQueens(int row, Integer[] columns, ArrayList<Integer[]> results) {
    if (row == GRID_SIZE) { // Found valid placement
        results.add(columns.clone()); 
    } else {
        for (int col = 0; col < GRID_SIZE; col++) {         
            if (checkValid(columns, row, col)) {
                columns[row] = col; // Place queen
                placeQueens(row + 1, columns, results); 
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Source for question/code: Cracking the Coding Interview. Link to complete code: https://github.com/gaylemcd/ctci/blob/master/java/Chapter%209/Question9_9/Question.java

Comment: This has nothing to do with Generics. Even if the values were int, Java autoboxes them to Integer class when required. int is a primitive type where as Integer is the wrapping class for this primitive type int. Try reading about primtive data types in Java and Autoboxing/Unboxing.

Comment: The usage here is totally opinion based.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, it's a straightforward mistake. You could use `int[]` and the code would behave the same (except it would be less wasteful).

Comment: @NathanHughes In general, yes. In this specific case that is irrelevant.

Comment: There is no advantage in using `Integer[]` instead of `int[]` in this example, but there are some "general" advantages: for example the default value. Even though `null` is pretty meaningless it is still better than `0`. And another advantage is that `Integer[]` is an array of an object type whereas `int[]` can't be determined to be an array of `int` using generics. That is why `Arrays.asList(new int[]{1, 2, 3})` won't work as expected.

Comment: I Guess author is in Love with OO Fashion !

Answer (score 3):

In Java, `Integer` represents an object, while `int` is a primitive type. The `Integer` class supports more functions and can hold `null` values. In addition, `ArrayList` can only contain objects such as `Integer`.

```
ArrayList<int[]> results = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

In the revised code above, `int[]` would still work because it is considered an object. However, the author may be seeking consistency or would need the extra functionality of the `Integer` object. It is a matter of the author's preference or ignorance.

Comment: @Siguza Then I suppose the only reason is to gain more functionality?

Comment: Or maybe just a simple mistake?

Comment: I have edited the answer, please check if it is correct.

Comment: @biziclop mistake? What about having a null  reference?

Comment: @joeyrohan Thanks, I just made a silly mistake in the answer :P

Comment: @joeyrohan Where is that relevant in the posted code? I can't see a single null check. Every time an element of the array is accessed, it is unboxed straight away.

Comment: @biziclop Are you referring to the code in the question?

Comment: He referring about the code and your answer *" the developer may be seeking consistency or would need the extra functionality of the `Integer` object"*. There is no reason to either use `Integer` or `Integer[]` here and that developer didn't use any of the existing "extra functionality" :P.

Comment: @Tom These are only the methods with `Integer[]` passed in as a parameter, the author may need to access the functionality where the methods are called.

Comment: @DizzyCode We can hypothesize about code that isn't in the post, but as the question is about this specific snippet, the answer really is that there is no good reason to use `Integer[]`.

Comment: @biziclop I am just hypothesizing on the reasons. Since I am not the author, I wouldn't know for sure. As I have stated in my answer, it may just be due to the author's preference.

Comment: @biziclop *"We can hypothesize about code that isn't in the post"* We can or we follow the posted link and read the full code :P. And no, the developer just uses unboxing/autoboxing and nothing else. So `Integer` and `Integer[]` are pointless here.

Comment: @DizzyCode Check out the full code then [here](https://github.com/gaylemcd/ctci/blob/master/java/Chapter%209/Question9_9/Question.java), in particular the `clear()` method. Now, I'm no Sherlock Holmes but my guess is that the person who wrote this code was blissfully unaware of the difference between `int` and `Integer`.

Comment: @biziclop Thanks for clearing up the issue. I have made a final edit to reflect that it is a matter of preference or ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

You may think that the first line of the main (from the link you've provided):

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> results = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
```

Must use Integer, but as comments suggest, it's not the case.

```
ArrayList<int[]> results = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

Would also worked. So it's just the author's preference in that case.

Comment: But `int[]` **is** an object.

Comment: @JFPicard -  List<int[]> a =new ArrayList<int[]>(); works perfectly fine.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't aware of that... I was thinking that even a primitive type array -> primitive type. I will edit.